# multi-dimensional stdClass Object

Tags: php

I've got a rather large multidimensional stdClass Object being outputted from a json feed with PHP.

It goes about 8 or 9 steps deep and the data that I need is around 7 steps in.

I'm wondering if I can easily grab one of the entires instead of doing this:

echo $data->one->two->anotherone->gettinglong->omg->hereweare;

I'm saying this because the data structure may change over time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to parse the object into an array and search the array for the wanted values, it just keeps looping through each level of the object.

```
function parseObjectArrayToArray($objectPassed, &$in_arr = array()) { 
    foreach($objectPassed as $element) {
        if(is_object($element) || is_array($element)) {
            parseObjectArrayToArray($element,$in_arr);
        } else {
            // XML is being passed, need to strip it
            $element = strip_tags($element); 

            // Trim whitespace
            $element = trim($element);

            // Push to array  
            if($element != '' && !in_array($element,$in_arr)) {                
                  $in_arr[] = $element;  
            } 
        }
    }
    return $in_arr;
}
```

How to call

```
$parsed_obj_arr = parseObjectArrayToArray($objectPassed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without searching through whats probably inefficient.
Json is a structured data object with the purpose of eliminating something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If the datastructure can change, but doesn't very often, your best bet is to write a wrapper object so you will only have to change a path at a single point on change:

```
class MyDataWrapp {
   public $json;
   function __construct($jsonstring){
      $this->json = json_decode($jsonstring);
   }
   function getHereWeAre(){
       return $this->json->one->two->anotherone->gettinglong->omg->hereweare;
   }
}
```

If the datastructure changes dramatically and constantly, I'd `json_decode` as an array of arrays, and probably use `RecursiveFilterIterator`.